# get cell fill color using openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I would like to get the background fill value for a particular cell in a sheet using openpyxl. I thought that the selected answer from this post [openpyxl : Is there a way to search an Excel spreadsheet for cells with specific fill color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948928/openpyxl-is-there-a-way-to-search-an-excel-spreadsheet-for-cells-with-specific) would help me, but it isn't working properly.
Here is my current code:

```
wb1 = Workbook()

ws1 = wb1.create_sheet('new sheet', 0)
ws1.cell(1,1).value = 0.5  # cell A1 

rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='num', start_value=0, start_color='FFFFFF',
                      end_type='num', end_value=1, end_color='FF007F')
ws1.add(range_string='A1', cfRule=rule)

print('rgb_fg: ', ws1.cell(1,1).fill.fgColor.rgb)
print('rgb_bg: ', ws1.cell(1,1).fill.bgColor.rgb)
```

output:

```
rgb_fg: 00000000
rgb_bg: 00000000
```

Since I assigned 0.5 as the value of cell "A1" in ws1, then I would have no reason to think that the rgb of this cell would be 00000000 (black). It should be a light salmon red color, which is what I get if the sheet is saved and I view it.

*Note I printed fgColor and bgColor just to cover all my bases (or the ones I can think of)*

Perhaps something funky happens when a ColorScaleRule is applied to a cell so its fill value can't be read in the way I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting is not handled the same way as static colors. Background colors from those conditional rules are dynamic and therefore left to only be applied by spreadsheet software, not the library itself. Therefore, you will not be able to determine this value with openpyxl.

The good news is that if you were to save the spreadsheet, you would see that your code is correct and the cell does appear pink.